# Segfault with Asio on async_accept but can't figure out

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I got a segfault in the following code, but I can't figure out why...
I'm trying to have a minimal asynchronous local socket server without using classes like it is done in the examples to see better the calls. I've been careful not to forget anything, but it's been 2h I search without finding why I've this Segfault...

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

const char * const path = "/var/local/serv.socket";
asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor * acceptor;
asio::io_service io_service;

void handle_co(std::error_code ec){
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Connection !";
}

void loop(){
    auto socket = new asio::local::stream_protocol::socket(io_service);
    acceptor->async_accept(*socket, [socket](std::error_code ec){
        handle_co(ec);
        socket->close();
        delete socket;
        loop();
    });
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::remove(path);
    asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint endpoint(path);
    asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor.listen();
    loop();

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

...Even if you just have to compile and run this code, this is what valgrind gives me :

```
==20787== Invalid read of size 8
==20787==    at 0x418E14: asio::basic_io_object<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::local::stream_protocol>, true>::get_service() (basic_io_object.hpp:208)
==20787==    by 0x411909: asio::async_result<asio::handler_type<loop()::{lambda(std::error_code)#1}, void (std::error_code)>::type>::type asio::basic_socket_acceptor<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::local::stream_protocol> >::async_accept<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::stream_socket_service<asio::local::stream_protocol>, loop()::{lambda(std::error_code)#1}>(asio::basic_socket<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::stream_socket_service<asio::local::stream_protocol> >&, asio::handler_type&&, std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::basic_socket>::value, void>::type*) (basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1018)
==20787==    by 0x4117BE: loop() (main.cpp:23)
==20787==    by 0x41188C: main (main.cpp:33)
==20787==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==20787== 
==20787== 
==20787== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==20787==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==20787==    at 0x418E14: asio::basic_io_object<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::local::stream_protocol>, true>::get_service() (basic_io_object.hpp:208)
==20787==    by 0x411909: asio::async_result<asio::handler_type<loop()::{lambda(std::error_code)#1}, void (std::error_code)>::type>::type asio::basic_socket_acceptor<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::local::stream_protocol> >::async_accept<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::stream_socket_service<asio::local::stream_protocol>, loop()::{lambda(std::error_code)#1}>(asio::basic_socket<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::stream_socket_service<asio::local::stream_protocol> >&, asio::handler_type&&, std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<asio::local::stream_protocol, asio::basic_socket>::value, void>::type*) (basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1018)
==20787==    by 0x4117BE: loop() (main.cpp:23)
==20787==    by 0x41188C: main (main.cpp:33)
```

Comment: Did you run your program through a debugger?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you can't delete the socket from within the `async_accept` handler; try leaking the socket, to confirm.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet yup, but valgrind is generally better than gdb for this kind of stuff... except the stack frame looks weird : the segfault happens in get_service(), and the frame just top of this is "only" a static_cast that should not do anything else...

Comment: @Collin : It shouldn't (normally, nothing is done with the socket from asio) and commenting the delete doesn't change anything (and actually, this code is not even reached since the pb happens in loop() and not in run() )

Comment: Oh, seems like bt gives a faked line number (I hadn't seen the line began above). Actually, it's line 1016 in async_accept (then there is indeed a get_service()

Comment: Well found it, stupid copy paste mistake >.<

Comment: When debugging a crash, you should definitely look at gdb as well as valgrind. They tell you different things. If you don't get any information about the state of the program at the time that it crashed, then you're going to have a hard time fixing the problem.

Comment: I know ;) I aways use gdb first, then if it's memory pb, I look at valgrind... But here, it was just the line numbers that messed me up cause It's been a while I haven't code C++. Well, I let this post anyway if some like to play the game of "where is the stupid mistake" :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have scope name collisions. At the global scope you declare `acceptor * acceptor` and then declare `acceptor` in `main()` and initialize it.

Later, inside `loop()` function you use uninitialized `acceptor*` and it crash. Replace **aceptor** initialization like this and its works:

```
acceptor = new asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor(io_service);
acceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor->bind(endpoint);
acceptor->listen();
```